# Retrieving value from an array of JSON objects

Tags: java, arrays, json

I'm trying to retrieve 2 values from an object that is within an array.
I want to get where (task = renewals and taskStatus is complete)

Object:

```
"policies": [
    {
      "policyNumber": "000000000000",
      "policyDetails": {
        "a": "55375",
        "b": "2018-01-20",
        "c": "060",
        "d": "071",
        "e": "IL",
        "f": "012",
        "g": "A",
        "h": "G"
      },
      "tasks": [
        {
          "task": "bills",
          "eligibility": false,
          "intent": null,
          "taskStatus": "Status Unavailable",
          "enrollmentStatus": false,
          "orderNumber": "",
          "reasonDescription": null
        },
        {
          "task": "renewals",
          "eligibility": null,
          "intent": null,
          "taskStatus": "Not Applicable",
          "enrollmentStatus": false,
          "orderNumber": "1",
          "reasonDescription": null
        }
    ]
 }
]
```

To get the value can I do something along the lines

```
if (cPolicy.get().getTasks().getTask("renewals")&& cPolicy.get().getTasks().getTaskStatus("complete") {
}
```

How do I get the values?

Comment: What's the language?

Comment: Hi! When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful info in it. There was also a toolbar full of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area showing what your post would look like when posted, located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it). Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please specify programming language you're using in tags

Comment: Apologies, this is in Java

Comment: Have you already mapped your JSON into an appropriate model class and iterated over it or is there always just a single object in the array?

Comment: I'd recommend using [Gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here your solution is, I have simply modified you complete JSON

```
JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(from);
jsonNode.get("policies").get(0).get("tasks").get(0).get("eligibility")
```

Example

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Json {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File from = new File("abc.txt"); 
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(from);
    System.out.println(jsonNode.get("policies").get(0).get("tasks").get(0).get("eligibility"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

JSON Example file abc.txt

```
  {
"policies": [
    {
      "policyNumber": "000000000000",
      "policyDetails": {
        "a": "55375",
        "b": "2018-01-20",
        "c": "060",
        "d": "071",
        "e": "IL",
        "f": "012",
        "g": "A",
        "h": "G"
      },
      "tasks": [
        {
          "task": "bills",
          "eligibility": false,
          "intent": null,
          "taskStatus": "Status Unavailable",
          "enrollmentStatus": false,
          "orderNumber": "",
          "reasonDescription": null
        },
        {
          "task": "renewals",
          "eligibility": null,
          "intent": null,
          "taskStatus": "Not Applicable",
          "enrollmentStatus": false,
          "orderNumber": "1",
          "reasonDescription": null
        }
    ]
 }
]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was a great help